# Refer file from previouse directory in a job/transformation in kettle

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I encounter a situation in a Job/transformation in the kettle (PDI) where I need to refer a job/transformation which is in the directory which is above the current directory.

Eg: The directory structure is like this. /home/ubuntu/mainETL/Jobs/trans.

For the job existed in mainETL, all the paths of jobs/trans are referred as ${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}/Jobs/testjob.kjb. for transformation, ${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}/Jobs/trans/testtrans.ktr.

But I encounter a situation where,  for the job existed in mainETL refer a job/trans existed in /home/ubuntu directory.

Someone pls suggest the solution. Thank you/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}/..

Note: if you’re using Pentaho 8 or above you should use the variable

${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}

As the other one is now deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you provide me with an example, where i refer a job/trans in the root job which in existed in the directory which is above the root directory. eg: root job is in /home/ubuntu/mainETL. and the job is there in /home/ubuntu/testjob.kjb. How this job is referrred in main job with variables. Thank you

Comment: ${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}/../testjob.kib

Comment: this is not working to set variables using ${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}